# JavaScript - Converting arrays to maps

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Given an array of objects:

```
var projects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Trader Portal'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Risk Engine'
    },
];
```

What is the most elegant way of converting it into the following structure - essentially and array of the ids along with a map of the objects:

```
{
    projects: [
        1,
        2
    ],
    projectMap: {
        1: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Trader Portal'
        },
        2: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Risk Engine'
        }
    }
}
```

I did this using underscore (see below or my [codepen](http://codepen.io/nareshbhatia/pen/KMdKJe)), but is there a better way? For example can this be done in a more declarative way using functional programming? Is there a way to genericize the code to work on an array of any type of objects?

```
var projects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Trader Portal'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Risk Engine'
    },
];

var result = {};

result.projects = _.map(projects, function(project) {
  return project.id;
});

result.projectMap = {};
_.each(projects, function(project) {
  result.projectMap[project.id] = project;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the new arrow functions, and the `map` & `reduce` Array methods, you can further simplify this:

```
var projects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Trader Portal'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Risk Engine'
    },
];

var projectMap = {
    projects: projects.map(p => p.id),
    projectMap: projects.reduce((obj, p) => {
      obj[p.id] = p;
      return obj;
    }, {})
};
```

Or maybe having an array of IDs is not necessary as you can easily get just the keys:

```
var projectMap = projects.reduce((obj, p) => {
    obj[p.id] = p;
    return obj;
}, {});

var projectIds = Object.keys(projectMap);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're just interested in the second example from [@jeremija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1095379/jeremija), then Ramda has a function built-in for this, [`indexBy`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#indexBy), which you can use [like this](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.21.0#?code=var%20projects%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Trader%20Portal%27%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27Risk%20Engine%27%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0A%0AindexBy%28prop%28%27id%27%29%2C%20projects%29%3B%0A):

```
R.indexBy(R.prop('id'), projects);
```

Comment: That's indeed short and sweet. Thanks for sharing, @ScottSauyet.

Comment: This is actually the most functional way

Answer (score 1):

VanillaJS implementation:

```
var result = {projectMap: {}};
result.projects = projects.map(p => p.id);
projects.forEach(p => {
  result.projectMap[p.id] = p;
});
```

Or even simpler with reduce:

```
result.projectMap = projects.reduce((c, p) => (c[p.id] = p, c), {});
```

We start here from empty hash `{}`, and extend carry(`c`) with new project(`p`) on each reduce iteration.

Comment: love your answer! I wish I can mark both yours and jeremija's as correct - as they are both aiming at the same approach (just that the style is slightly different). However, given only one choice, I am marking jeremija's as correct for suggesting that I don't need the array of ids in the result - it can be derived from the map. However, I am upvoting your answer.